# Need help with keeping Battlefield profile from PS3 and moving to PS4 With region change

Tags: battlefield-4

OK, so I realize this is kinda complicated but I haven't had any answers from other various forums so I'm trying it again here.

I had a PS3 that I purchased in the USA some years ago. I moved a few years later to Europe and bought the vanilla Battlefield 4 disc in EU game store, worked fine in my US PS3. I played for a couple years, unlocked weapons, upgrades, etc. and really loved the online play. I sold my old PS3 and games for credit at a game shop and bought a new PS4 here in EU zone recently. I know I need PS Plus to play online on the PS4 now, but I haven't done it yet until I know exactly what my options are.

I want to buy the Battlefield 4 Premium with all DLC, maps for online play, etc. AND use my same profile from my PS3 BF4 days with all unlocks, upgrades, etc. The only game store in my area doesn't have the BF4 Premium disc for PS4, just the basic game. Guy told me I can buy the vanilla BF4 for PS4 from them, buy PS Plus membership for whatever length of time, then purchase the DLC for BF4 from the PS Store. BUT... he said I will need to create a new PSN Account with an EU Region country (maybe UK for English speaking options, etc.) and then he said I'll need to start completely from beginning with BF4 at Level One, that I will lose all unlocks/upgrades, etc from my old profile on PS3, as THIS IS the only option if I want to play BF4 Premium on PS4.

Anyone know the real deal on this advice? Can I keep my BF4 Profile on an EU PS4, purchase DLC from PS Store, purchase PS Plus and be able to play the Premium maps?

Thank you for any help!!